# PostgreSQL Stored procedure for Insert or Update table

Tags: postgresql-11

I previous years i was working a lot with MSSQL and oracle databases as admin and dev. Now i started to use PostgreSQL.
From my opinion is a different dimension, and in the community is hard to find a proper solution.

In my case I want to create a stored procedure for insert or update table and returning ID of the row.

PostgreSQL version 11

Table :

```
   CREATE TABLE "TestRunManagement"."ValuesTable" (
    id int4 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    actualvalue varchar NULL,
    expectedvalue varchar NULL,
    success bool NOT NULL,
    "comment" varchar NULL,
    idmes int4 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT valuestable_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT valuestable_un UNIQUE (idmes)
);
```

Fist i do a working code after that will replace DECLARE with CREATE PROCEDURE name
This is a code written in beaver:

```
do $$
DECLARE 
    _idmes int;
    _actualvalue varchar;
    _success boolean;
    _comm varchar;
    _expectedvalue varchar;
begin
    _actualvalue:='10';
    _expectedvalue:='10';
   _success = 0;
    _comm:='This is a comment';
    _idmes :=7;
insert
    into
    "TestRunManagement"."ValuesTable" ( actualvalue,
    expectedvalue,
    success,
    "comment",
    idmes)
values (
    _actualvalue,
    _expectedvalue,
    _success,
    _comm,
    _idmes)
/*  values (
    '12',
    '3',
    false,
    'bčxfgfdgfdlas',
    7)*/
on
conflict(idmes) do
update
set
    "comment" = EXCLUDED.comment,
    success = EXCLUDED.success ;
end; $$
```

After running this query I get following results.

```
SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "_actualvalue" does not exist
  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "ValuesTable.actualvalue".
  Position: 119


Error position: line: 27 pos: 118
```

In my opinion, postgreSQL is a tough nut to crack.

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/KaCkCKY5

Comment: Btw: why start a new project with the somewhat outdated version 11 and not 15?

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name. I have read many of your comments in fund exchange, they have been very helpful.
For writing scrips I use beaver.
the company uses this version, plans to switch to 15 in the future, until then I'm struggling on 11